# Can I use the "UGC" link attribute to mark paragraphs of content submitted by users?

Tags: seo, google, links, nofollow, user-generated-content

Google recently advised us to use the following link attributes:

- nofollow
- sponsored
- ugc

"dofollow" is by default if not stated.

So, sponsored is for affiliate links (for example) and "ugc" is "user-generated content".

Here's my problem: I have a site with a ton of UGC. I manage a conference directory and every conference organizer uploads a lot of content (about 300 - 500 words) of UGC.

BUT - the content that is being uploaded is not a link of course. Is there a way to perhaps add this tag "ugc" to a paragraph class or similar?

How do I let Google know that 3 or 4 paragraphs of a page are UGC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UGC is only for backlink in user generated content. Not for paragraph.

Please let me share my point of view : this tag is only to help google classifying those kind of link for machine learning, you've no interest of adding it.

For paragraph, why do you want to tag it?
- if it's just a fear of google based on google declaration : forget it.
- if it's good content in the same semandtic that your main content : keep it it's a good and free thing
- if it's bad quality content, just remove it, don't hope tagging it will prevent from problem.

Globaly, if you not proud of some content, don't use it, don't display it, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. Google doesn't ask, and there's no way to tell them.

Like Patrick mentioned, if it's spammy and/or otherwise problematic content, just delete it through moderation. Otherwise, you're running a conference directory, so it makes sense that most of the content that Google indexes is user-generated. Google is smart enough to deal with that.